# Is it possible to serve a react app on diffrent url on `npm start`

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

By default in a react app , npm start serve the url in `http://localhost:3000/`. I want to serve the application in a different url such as `http://localhost:3000/my-app` in development mode. How can I do it?

I don't want to change the app directory. Instead of serving the app on `localhost:3000` I want it to serve at `localhost:3000/my-app` url. Which means `localhost:3000/my-app` will be the default url.Here's the reference image

[image]

The local should be `http://localhost:3000/my-app` insted of `http://localhost:3000/`

Thanks for advance.

Comment: Just add a route called `\my-app` and handle it like you will handle your homepage.

Answer (score 2):

In windows, you can change all the parts of the url from package.json.
just modify the script, `start` for this case, to be like this

```
"start": "set PUBLIC_URL=myapp&&set HOST=DOMAIN-NAME&&set PORT=AppPort&&react-scripts start"
```

This will effectively configure npm to open your browser using the url

```
http://DOMAIN-NAME:AppPort/myapp
```

Also you can configure HTTPS protocol and certificate as well

```
"start": "set PUBLIC_URL=myapp&&set HTTPS=true&&set SSL_CRT_FILE=[path to certificate]&&set SSL_KEY_FILE=[path to key file]&&set HOST=DOMAIN-NAME&&set PORT=AppPort&&react-scripts start"
```

which will be open in

```
https://DOMAIN-NAME:AppPort/myapp
```

the solution for other OS will be similar

Comment: Thank you for the clear example. I can verify this works in Windows, as long as nothing else is running on the selected port (like IIS).

Answer (score 1):

Add `homepage` key in package.json:

**"homepage" : "http://localhost:3000/my-app",**

This will serve everything from this sub-directory.

Comment: No worked. I don't want to change the app directory. Instead of serving the app on http://localhost:3000/ I want it to serve at http://localhost:3000/my-app url. Which means http://localhost:3000/my-app will be the default url

Comment: not working. Although "homepage" is used within the scripts, but for somehow it does not affect the final url

Answer (score 0):

In route definitions, look for root directory definition. You may see something like this.

```
<Route exact path='/' component={StartPage} />
```

change path from `'/'` to `'/myapp'`
i.e,

```
<Route exact path='/myapp' component={StartPage} />
```

Comment: like this ?  . `const Routes = ({history}) => {
  return (
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <div>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/myapp"
          component={AppLayout}
        />
      </div>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  );
}`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to run your localhost on subdomain, just do this :

`"start": "PUBLIC_URL=my-app react-scripts start",`